# How to output to a sequential file from SORT?

Tags: mainframe, jcl

I am new to the IBM Mainframe and am in need of sorting some data (provided by my lecturer) and writing the output to a previously-created sequential dataset.

```
//RUN1     EXEC NEWDS,MLQ=CW,LLQ=DATA1, 
//          QTY=TRK,PRI=100,SEC=50,   
//          TYPE=BASIC,             
//          RECSIZE=80,FM='FB,DSORG=PS'
```

The above JCL allocated a new PS dataset and now I need to write the output of a SORT to Data1
The JCL below is the code I have so far for this process

```
//MYJCL2 JOB 1,NOTIFY=&SYSUID                                     
//SORT     EXEC PGM=SORT                                          
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                            
//SORTIN   DD DSN=&SYSUID..LABS.JCL(AREACODE),DISP=SHR            
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=&SYSUID..CW.DATA1(AREACODE),DISP=SHR            
  SORT FIELDS=(5,17,CH,D)
```

Comment: Can you remove the `sorting` tag and use the `dfsort` or `syncsort` tag instead as appropriate, please. You could also fix the space before RUN1, which is not valid.

Answer (score 2):

```
//MYJCL2 JOB 1,NOTIFY=&SYSUID                                     
//SORT     EXEC PGM=SORT                                          
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                            
//SORTIN   DD DSN=&SYSUID..LABS.JCL(AREACODE),DISP=SHR            
//SORTOUT  DD DSN=&SYSUID..CW.DATA1,DISP=OLD            
  SORT FIELDS=(5,17,CH,D)
```

Your problem is that you are specifying a member-name `(AREACODE)` on your output dataset, but it is just a plain sequential file, and only a PDS (Partitioned Dataset) or PDSE (Extended of the same) can have members. Remove that, so that the system is no longer confused as to whether you are using a PS or a PDS/PDSE.

I've changed the DISP=SHR on the output dataset to DISP=OLD. This will prevent you possibly mangling the file whilst updating it at the same time. With DISP=OLD, it can only be open in one place at a time.